# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on my android app and the Xml is find

Tags: android

I have met a problem follow:

```
07-20 18:10:52.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3019): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lok.camfly.CamFlyCtrlMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.lok.camfly-2/pkg.apk]
```

I have search about this problem on google. So i check my xml and found that it is find. And the class name is match with the xml Activity name.

Could someone help me? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you have used any jar/libraries are inside of your project.?

Answer (score 0):

Please try and check if you have mentioned "package" entry in Manifest file. This could be the reason for the issue. Share the result.